# Pandas apply, map and iterrows behaving strangely

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to prune texts in a list based on texts in another list. The following function works fine when called directly on two lists

```
def remove_texts(texts, texts2):
to_remove = []
for i in texts2:
    if i in texts:
        to_remove.append(i)
texts = [j for j in texts if j not in to_remove]
return texts
```

However, the following does nothing and I get no errors

```
df_other.texts = df_other.texts.map(lambda x: remove_texts(x, df_other.to_remove_split))
```

Nor does the following. Again no error is returned

```
for i, row in df_other.iterrows():
    row['texts'] = remove_texts(row['texts'], row['to_remove_split'])
```

Any thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually want to find the **set difference** between `texts`
and `texts2`. Assume that they contain:

```
texts = [ 'AAA', 'BBB', 'DDD', 'EEE', 'FFF', 'GGG', 'HHH' ]
texts2 =  [ 'CCC', 'EEE' ]
```

Then, the shortes solution is to compute just the set difference,
without using *Pandas*:

```
set(texts).difference(texts2)
```

gives:

```
{'AAA', 'BBB', 'DDD', 'FFF', 'GGG', 'HHH'}
```

Or if you want just a **list** (not *set*), write:

```
sorted(set(texts).difference(texts2))
```

And if for some reason you want to use *Pandas*, then start from
creting of both DataFrames:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(texts, columns=['texts'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(texts2, columns=['texts'])
```

Then you can compute the set difference as:

```
df.query('texts not in @df2.texts')
```

or

```
df.texts[~df.texts.isin(df2.texts)]
```